# What is the exact time on Minecraft that is sunrise?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What time does the sun rise on Minecraft? I would like to know because I am building a map where it needs that time for the map. By this I mean when the sun creates a purple color in the sky.

Comment: I think it was 0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Minecraft day is 20 (real-life) minutes long, which translates into 24000 game ticks (there are 20 ticks per second).

Sunrise is implemented as the last part of the day-night cycle and is 90 seconds (1800) ticks) long (according to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Time)), starting at around game time 22200

when the sky will look like this (facing due east)

[image: Start of sunrise phase]

to game time 0 when the sky will look like this (also facing due east)

[image: End of sunrise phase]

The easiest way to detect sunrise is to use the [daylight sensor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Daylight_Sensor) that has been introduced in the snapshots in combination with a [comparator](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Comparator)

Answer (score 2):

22796 is the soonest a directly exposed daylight sensor powers on in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

the day starts at 0+k*20(minutes)*60(s/min)*20(ticks/s)=0+k*24000 ticks with the sunrise being the 1.5 minutes before that point

the full day-night cycle is 20 minutes and minecraft time is measured in ticks (of which there are 20 in each seconds

Comment: Could you please give me a round number?

Comment: What value would you give the variable k?

Comment: @Meraj99 k is the number of days since generating the world